# I have a raster (ascii format) with text values. How do I convert it to numeric values in either R or ArcGIS?

Tags: r, arcgis, raster

See a sample of the file below. The file appears to be in an ArcGIS ascii format, but reads as all zeros if you import it as a raster to either ArcGIS or R. I would like to convert each of the text classes (16 total) to numeric form while keeping nodata as -9999. The file is 15 mb. Any help is appreciated.

cols          1520
nrows          1550
xllcorner      7517937.93364
yllcorner      -3188304.43924
cellsize       25
NODATA_value -9999
"-9999" "SE" "SW" "N" "N"
"-9999" "-9999" "N" "SE" "N"
"-9999" "-9999" "N" "SW" "N"

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
x <- readLines('file.asc')
x <- gsub("N", 0, x)
x <- gsub("S", 180, x)
# etc.
writeLines(x, 'newfile.asc')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This almost works, but it incorrectly replaces certain patterns in the data. For example, if the line: "N" "NNE" "NNW" "S" "-9999" should read "4" "6" "7" "-9999", but instead read something like "4441" "4414" "9" "-9999" Is there a way to specify exact matches, so that "N" only replaces N's and not the N in NNE? Or maybe I need to specify the delimiter when the file is read in?

Comment: Ok and thanks again @RobertH, I have fixed this by specifying that the text string being searched for must start/end each word: x<-gsub("\\bN\\b",0,x). The only issue now, is that it is still storing each 'word' as a text string, and will not coerce to numeric. So the output is: "-9999" "4" "2" "1" "1", rather than simply -9999 4 2 1 1.